# Unknown error when printing solutions in for statment

Tags: java, for-loop

I'm fairly new to java and I'm attempting to create a simple java program that checks for arithmetic and geometric sequences and lists the desired amount of terms from the sequence out. Everything in the program works properly until the printing of the next terms in the for statement occurs. There is no errors, and I can't find anything wrong. Any help is appreciated.

```
if(num2-num1 == num3-num2){
    d = num2-num1;
    System.out.println("This is a arithmetic sequence.\nCommon Difference = " + d);
    System.out.println("How many terms of this sequence would you like?");

    int a = scanner.nextInt();

    for(int i = 1; i >= a; i++){
        num3 += d;
        System.out.println(num3);
    }
    suc = 1;
}
```

Comment: What doesn't work about it?

Comment: If `a` is given a value of `2`, the for loop will never start.

Comment: spit out the whole program

Answer (score 3):

Please change `i>=a` to `i<=a`.

Comment: good catch. Otherwise the loop will go on indefinitely if a< 1 e.g 0 , -1 I think

Answer (score 0):

your `for` loop parameters are wrong :

change the for loop :

```
for(int i = 1; i >= a; i++)
```

to something like this :

```
for(int i = 1; i <= a; i++)
```